# Drawing an animation using an image sequence and arrays?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

As a not so experienced programmer like you wonderful superheroes of the Stack, I am pulling my hair out of something I believe might be incredibly simple.

My goal is to have an animated background for the title screen of a game I'm creating. (Using Slick2D)
Like how *Minecraft* has an animated background on their title screen.
After searching for answers I have been trying to use this one method somebody suggested on a forum.
However I can not seem to grasp it.

Here's the code:

```
package com.polython.game;

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState{
    Image[] bg;
    Image logo;

    public Menu(int State){}

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
        //Bit of code that generates a .png sequence. 
        //A.K.A. The magic of the Main Menu.

        final int bgFrames = 251;

        Image[] bg = new Image[bgFrames];
        String fileLocation = new String();
        for (int i = 1; i < bgFrames; i++){ 
            fileLocation = "res/img/bg/" + i + ".png";
            bg[i] = new Image(fileLocation); 
        }       
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        logo.draw(145, 25, .5f); //Centering the logo
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 50); 
        g.drawString("Play", 180, 115);
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
        int posX = Mouse.getX();
        int posY = Mouse.getY();

        //Not sure why this is here so early. 
        if((posX > 100 && posX<311) && (posY > 209 && posY < 260)){
            if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
                sbg.enterState(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public int getID(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The pictures are all in "/res/img/bg" from 1.png to 250.png

The error I get commonly goes like this:

> Sat Nov 08 21:08:35 CST 2014 INFO:Slick Build #237 Sat Nov 08 21:08:35
>   CST 2014 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.9.0 Sat Nov 08 21:08:35 CST 2014
>   INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 768 x 1360 x 32 @60Hz Sat Nov 08 21:08:35
>   CST 2014 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 640 x 360 x 0 @0Hz Sat Nov 08
>   21:08:35 CST 2014 INFO:Starting display 640x360 Sat Nov 08 21:08:35
>   CST 2014 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true Sat Nov 08 21:08:35 CST 2014
>   INFO:Controllers not available [Lorg.newdawn.slick.Image;@26d0fffc
>   [Lorg.newdawn.slick.Image;@46446e0c Sat Nov 08 21:08:37 CST 2014
>   ERROR:null java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.polython.game.Menu.render(Menu.java:35)   at
>   org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.render(StateBasedGame.java:199)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:688)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
>     at com.polython.game.Game.main(Game.java:29) Sat Nov 08 21:08:37 CST
>   2014 ERROR:Game.render() failure - check the game code.
>   org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.render() failure - check the
>   game code.    at
>   org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:691)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
>     at com.polython.game.Game.main(Game.java:29)

I hope I can get some help soon, It'd be appreciated :)
Thanks guys,
-First Timer

Comment: note: when using bg.draw(x, y); under the render method, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you use and `ArrayList` instead. Plus it looks like the error is coming from the `g.drawString()`. How about try to remove that line and seeing if that works, if it does then the reason is because the X, and Y is making the string draw outside the JFrame. This is a stupid thing, but I always get errors from those. And that is the main problem, because you are not even drawing the `bg[]` images. Also you are creating another `Image[] bg` variable inside the `init()` method. That isn't necessary. First create `private` variables outside the methods.

```
private static List<BufferedImage> bg = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
private static Integer time = 0;
```

`ArrayList`'s are better. Then inside the `init()` method, make it where it adds the images to the list.

```
public void init() {
    Integer max = 250;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        try {
            bg.add(ImageIO.read(new File("res/img/bg/" + i + ".png")));
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

then inside of your `render()` method do this

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2;
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    }
    // The stuff you already had
    g.drawImage(g.get(time), X, Y, null);
}
```

then inside of your `update()` method make it where the time is added up.

```
public void update() {
    if (time < bg.size()) {
        time++;
    }
    else {
        time = 0;
    }
}
```

then this should create the animation. Now if you didn't setup a FPS system, then in your main class file that is calling the `update()`, and `render()` methods, after it type

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000/FPS);
catch (Exception e) {}
```

you should put FPS as 60. Then this should work. If there is a problem, sorry cause I just typed the codes without Eclipse. I just did this from memory cause I always code these types of programs/games.

Comment: A few syntax errors were in there, but I managed to work around those. The only place I am managing to still get errors is under my render() method. Something is going on with the Graphics that's all. everything is works fine

Answer (score 0):

It was all a matter of missing certain things that needed to be declared, it is now working and looks beautiful!